# Two columns equal height only css (no display: table, table-row, table-cell)

Tags: css, height, equals

In CSS, I can do something like this:
[http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120612/Uk1Z8iZ1.png http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120612/Uk1Z8iZ1.png](http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120612/Uk1Z8iZ1.png)

But I've no idea how to change that to something like:
[http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120612/eI5sNTeu.png http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120612/eI5sNTeu.png](http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120612/eI5sNTeu.png)

***The height is not fixed***

**Please help me do it! Thank you all in advance!**

Comment: Is the container fixed height? Does the container need to grow with additional content in either column? Is a requirement that either column can be the fullest with content, or will one or the other reliably be always fuller than the other?

Comment: @Faust, The height is not fixed, the text in blocks is always different.

Comment: I'd go with Bfroh's solution, though Mononatelier's soln is the same, except he sets the padding/margin values to larger numbers, which would be safer.

Comment: @Faust, I specified in my answer that the values of `padding`/`margin` should be adjusted for the maximum height of the wrapper (instead of sticking with the value provided in my answer).

Comment: You have dead image links; could you please see if you can find the original images and re-include them, with imgur, via the image-adding button in the editor?

Answer (score 26):

I use this, pure css.

The html:

```
<div id="container" class="holder">
    <div id="column-one" class="even-height">TEXT</div>
    <div id="column-two" class="even-height">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.holder {
   overflow: hidden;
   clear:    both;
}
.holder .even-height {
   float: left;
   padding-bottom: 100000px;
   margin-bottom:  -100000px;
}
#column-one { width: 30%; }
#column-two { width: 70%; }
```

The columns can be any width you want actually.  Anyway, super simple and cross-browser friendly.

Comment: oops, i was beaten to it by @bfrohs.

Comment: content can be more than 100000px

Comment: what do you mean?  i've used this successfully for all my sites.

Comment: @MaxPopkin, o i see.  as long as the padding bottom and margin bottom (with negative sign) are the same, you should be okay.

Comment: @manonatelier, if the content of one of the columns is taller than 100,000 pixels, then the shorter column will not reach the bottom of the container. (Why is the content so tall? Don't ask me.)

Comment: i have yet to find a site with such a long height and so much content. this is more of insurance that the content of either will be served within these limits.

Comment: this method dramatically increases page paint time when column has `box-shadow` (checked in chrome with enabled continuous page repainting)

Comment: this doesn't work if columns have borders! (they won't be displayed)

Answer (score 9):

[Variable height wrapper with equal-height columns](http://jsfiddle.net/gZLN8/7/)

### HTML

```
<section class="wrapper">
    <section>a</section>
    <aside>b<br>c</aside>
</section>
```

### CSS

```css
/* Set @max-column-height to greater than the maximum height of the tallest column */
.wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:10px;
}
.wrapper > section {
    background:red;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    padding-bottom:1000px; /* @max-column-height */
    margin-bottom:-1000px; /* @max-column-height */
}
.wrapper > aside {
    background:orange;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    padding-bottom:1000px; /* @max-column-height */
    margin-bottom:-1000px; /* @max-column-height */
}
```

Comment: It should be without it: padding-bottom: 1000px; margin-bottom:-1000px;

Comment: @MaxPopkin, the `padding` and `margin` is what creates the equal-height columns.

Comment: But if the content is more than that, the desired result will not be!

Comment: @MaxPopkin, then simply change it to be more than the max column height... http://jsfiddle.net/gZLN8/5/

Comment: Hi, is it possible to put the content of the columns in the center, both vertically and horizontally speaking?

Comment: @Fab No, not using this technique, at least not one for fluid heights (and definitely not for text). It is, however, possible [using `display:table`](http://jsfiddle.net/gZLN8/75/). But watch out for [browser support](http://caniuse.com/css-table)---It isn't supported by IE7 and below.

Answer (score 2):

I like broh's/manonatelier's better (+1 to each), but if you really want a solution that is *utterly* independent of the amount of content inside, I would use the old technique of design 'hooks': http://jsfiddle.net/GTY8P/

...Uses more markup and CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Make a wrapper with a div like this :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">Box 1</div>
    <div class="box">Box 2</div>
</div>
```

Apply a style like that :

```
.wrapper {
    height: 400px;
}

.wrapper .box{
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 10px;
}​
```

Didn't try, but will work.

**EDIT** jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/NXjk4/

Comment: It should be without it: height: 400px;

Comment: @MaxPopkin You are right, sorry. I'll keep it here if somebody need it one day, if not a moderator will juste delete it.

Comment: Right. The answer is a bit misleading. The main reason you want to ever do this is that if you do not know the height. Specifying the height in the parent makes it all pointless.

Answer (score -1):

Check this

### **HTML**

```
<div class="box" >
    <div class="box1">TEXT</div>
    <div class="box2">TEXT</div>
</div>​
```

### **CSS**

```
    .box{
    background:#000;
    height:60px
}

.box1{
    float: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align:center;
}
.box2{
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-left:5px;
    text-align:center;
}​
```

**See the demo here :**   http://jsfiddle.net/X3UY9/1/

Comment: The height is not fixed! Always different!

Comment: @Enve, the height does *not* need to be specified. See mine and manonatelier's answers.

Comment: I feel for @MaxPopkin. His requirement of having an independent height (no hardcoded magic numbers) is my concern as well. The heights of the columns should be the same WITHOUT any restrictions on the max height whatsoever. I do not really want to resort to a javascript solution (eww) :)